# How to compile and run a simple java file in jenkins in windows

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-cli

Hi i want to run simple Hello World Java program using jenkins
Below is the program

```
public class Hello {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

My doubt is should i commit whole project or i need to commit only Hello.java file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want CI to work only with one java class then follow next steps:

1. Go to configuration page of your *job/project*
2. Select *"Execute Windows batch command"* from *"Add build step"* combobox
3. Type the compiling and run commands on Command field: `javac <your_class_name>.java java <your_class_name>`
4. Save configuration
5. Keep `<your_class_name>.java` file on the folder */Jenkins/workspace/*
6. Build the *project/job* by clicking *"Build Now"* link and see the Console Output

Comment: thanks for the answer, when i create normal java project it will be in folder structure, with .settings , bin, src, .classpath and .project , how to run whole project ?     It should pick up <your_class_name>.java file automatically , is there any way?

Comment: @Prasad, for such case there is a manual for simple freestyle java project: [TutorialsPoint manual](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.htm)

Comment: I Checked the tutorial, it didnt clear my doubt,
5. Keep <your_class_name>.java file on the folder /Jenkins/workspace/,  
For the 5th point , should i manual put the java file in that location?

Comment: If you want to build only with this file then ofc you need manually control its location. But if you use the tutorial for the whole project, then accordingly to its steps you need to link your project through the Jenkins web ui.

Comment: How to pass VM arguments for the java file in jenkins job??